# Getting value with htaccess and pagination for root

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, pagination

This url

```
example.com/videos/load.php?cat=video-category
```

would become

```
example.com/videos/video-category
```

Also, there is pagination & limit url

```
example.com/videos/load.php?cat=video-category&p=2&limit=20
```

it would become

```
example.com/videos/video-category?p=2&limit=20
```

(this links also work)

```
example.com/videos/video-category?p=2
example.com/videos/video-category?limit=20
```

Also, there is another root url

```
example.com/videos/load.php?cat=video-category&name=video-name
```

it would become

```
example.com/videos/video-category/video-name
```

Also, there is pagination & limit url

```
example.com/videos/load.php?cat=video-category&name=video-name&p=2&limit=20
```

And it would become

```
example.com/videos/video-category/video-name?p=2&limit=20
```

(this links also work)

```
example.com/videos/video-category/video-name?p=2
example.com/videos/video-category/video-name?limit=20
```

Here is my htaccess (into `videos` folder)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /videos/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+videos/load\.php\?cat=([^&\ ]+)&?([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ %1?%2 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ load.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA]
```

how to do this.. plz help me.. thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /videos/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+videos/load\.php\?cat=([^&\s]+)&name=([^&\s]+)&?(\S*)
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2?%3 [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+videos/load\.php\?cat=([^&\s]+)&?(\S*)
RewriteRule ^ %1?%2 [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ load.php?cat=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ load.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA]
```